# Как решить ошибку "No such file or directory" (Kotlin)?

Tags: json, kotlin

Суть проблемы в том, что приложение вылетает с ошибкой "Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" при открытии json файла

Код:

```
val jsonString = File("/data/data/ru.n.n/files/habit.json").readText()
        val gson = Gson()
        val habits = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject::class.java)
            .get("habits")
            .asJsonArray
            .map {
                gson.fromJson(it, DataClass::class.java)
            }
        titleList.addAll(habits)
```

Такой код работает (на моём устройстве, на другом уже не работает), но если в пути оставить только "habit.json", то приложение крашится

Файл лежит в папке assets, смотрел уже множество решений, у многих просто указано название файла без полного пути, и всё работает...

Comment: Файл, лежащий в assets не является файлом, он является Asset

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: @user7860670, не совсем понимаю смысла сказанного, т.е. например для файлов json надо создать обычную папку Assets? Просто опять же повторюсь, многие гайды подразумевают собой создание именно папки assets, где хранят эти файлы

Comment: Это у вас в проекте есть папка в которой лежит файл. А в собранном приложении никаких папок и файлов нет, файл становится Asset.